# How to display SQLSRV IMAGE in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, blob, laravel-query-builder

I am working on a application that uses data from a 3rd party server (MS SQLSRV) which I have only read-access to.

Images on that server is stored as IMAGE data type. I am using php (Laravel 5) as backend to a AngularJS frontend to display the images. I am unsure how to proceed.

```
$students = DB::table('StudentImage')->where('STUDENTID', $id)->get();
$image = imagecreatefromstring($students[0]->IMAGE1); // unrecognized format error
```

I have also tried this :

```
$db = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare("select IMAGE1 from [StudentImage] where [STUDENTID] = ?");
$stmt->execute([$id]);
$stmt->bindColumn('IMAGE1', $lob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

return response($lob, 200, ['Content-Type'=>'image/jpg']);
```

All I get is a 20x20 blank image. But, I can see the image in Navicat (DB Admin Tool).

How do I proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of head banging, I've figured this out. Turns out there's a default size limit for "text" fields in SQL Server. All you have to do is "reset" the size before running the `SELECT` query, using the `SET TEXTSIZE` command:

```
<?php

    DB::select('SET TEXTSIZE 10485760');

    $students = DB::table('StudentImage')->where('STUDENTID', $id)->get();
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($students[0]->IMAGE1);

?>
```

This will set the max size to 10 MB, which should be enough to display the image you'd like. This is probably what Navicat presets before running a query.